# Get HTML entity of character symbol in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, entity, symbols

If a square root symbol exists in a  I like to color it green. So I have something like this:

```
<div class=”cell”>foo</div>
<div class=”cell”>bar</div>
<div class=”cell”>&radic;</div>
<div class=”cell”>foo</div>
<div class=”cell”>&radic;</div>
```

My attempt with jQuery:

```
$(".value_spec_table_description_div_cs").each(function(){

    if ($(this).html() === "&radic;"){
        $(this).css("color" , "rgba(0,128,0,1.0)");
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately it seems html() is not converting the symbol √ into HTML entity again so the statement never returns true.

I tried a lot like:

```
var test = $("#table").html();

var html = $("<textarea/>").html(test).html();

alert(html);
```

Every special character is in entity unless the root square symbol **√** into `&radic;`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers normalise HTML when they convert it to a DOM. Short of making an Ajax request to get the source code of the page, writing a custom parser, finding the HTML you care about, and comparing *that* you can't really do this.

Better to just compare text:

```
if ($(this).text() === "√"){
```

Answer (score 1):

Like what @Quentin said. What jQuery sees is the rendered character `'√'` and not `'&radic;'`. Either you compare it with the rendered character or it's unicode equivalent `'\u221A'`, like so:

```
$('.cell').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === '\u221A') {
        $(this).css('color', 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 1.0)');
    }
});
```