# How will I write special characters written in my HTML code in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, special-characters

I wrote a special character in my HTML - &#873 to get a square root symbol. I am trying to get that button using innerText using javascript but it doesn't mean to work.

````
```else if (x.target.innerText == "&#8730"){
console.log("H")
    }
```
````

check out the code

Comment: If you have access to the DOM to set some specific value as innerText why don't you simply assign a custom class or an ID to the html element and then select it by that?

Comment: Maybe `'\u221A'` will work

Comment: log `x.target.innerText` and see what does it return, and  use that for ur condition.

Comment: "\u221A" worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers normalise HTML when they convert it to a DOM.
so it is better to compare the text:

```
if ($(this).text() === "√"){
```

Comment: Next time at least credit the post you took the answer from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60814270/2943218

Comment: How were you able to get that symbol on you keyboard?

Comment: It worked anyway when I copied and paste it.Thanks